# Reindex crawled data Solr 5.4.1

Tags: hadoop, solr, web-crawler

I have a Solr setup which is getting data from a webcrawler and has ~5Millions docs in it at present. This whole system is setup on the top of Hadoop.

Recently I have implemented autocomplete functionality to my Solr. Now the problem is since I have 5M records or data crawled from all over the web, I want to reindex the data without crawling those sites again. So is there anyway I could reindex the data which is already been indexed Or I will have to recrawl the sites again ?
Please advise.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I work on a python [SolrClient](https://github.com/moonlitesolutions/SolrClient) library and it has a handy reindexer module that was made specifically for this. It will either dump out your collection to filesystem in form of JSON docs or immediately index it into another collection.

http://solrclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reindexer.html

Here is how to reindex the collection.

```
    from SolrClient import SolrClient, IndexQ
    from SolrClient.helpers import Reindexer        
    r = Reindexer(SolrClient('http://localhost:8983/solr'), SolrClient('http://localhost:8983/solr'), source_coll='collection1', dest_coll='collection1', rows=10000)
    r.reindex()
```

I haven't tested re indexing the same collection since I usually re-index into a new collection and then switch an alias, but it should work alright.